# extension of operator

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, parabolic-pde

I need to work with this operator, with $X=L^2(\Omega)$, $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, $\lambda>0$ and $D(A)=\{u\in H^2(\Omega): \frac{\partial u}{\partial n}=0\}$:

\begin{align}
A:D(A)\subset X\to X\\
Au=-\Delta u +\lambda u
\end{align}
I proved that $A$ is sectorial. Now, to considerating all possible power space, I need to enlarge the space to $H^{-1}$. How is the argue that should I to use? Integration by parts? I also need that $A$ continues sectorial.

Recall that an operator is sectorial if there exists $a\in \mathbb{R}, \phi\in (0,\pi/2)$ and $M>0$ such that:

- the resolvent set contains the sector $S=\{\lambda\in \mathbb{C}; \phi\leq |\arg(\lambda-a)|\leq \pi, \lambda\neq a\}$;
- $\|(\lambda I-A)^{-1}\|\leq \frac{M}{|\lambda-a|}$, $\forall \lambda \in S$.

Comment: Ok, I've seen a theorem that if A is defined in a Hilbert space and is selfadjointed and positive, A continues sectorial. Now I just need to extend $A$ to a $L: D(A)\subset H^{-1}\to H^{-1}$.

Comment: If someone wants to use the embedding's sobolev, use with n=1.